# mock currently logged-in user in liferay for a unit test

Tags: java, junit, liferay, mockito

I'm new to liferay, I'm working on my first task.
I've created a method to check if a  given role/permission is assigned to a user.

I want to write a test class that checks if the given role is assigned to a current logged-in user?
How can I mock a currently logged-in user in a unit test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This approach will not always work, because you can be a part of a role that you do not have permission to view.

Instead, you can use `RoleLocalServiceUtil` and the methods therein to check role membership, and `ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil` to check permissions on a particular resource.

---

Update - In order to mock a user, you can use this snippet:

```
PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(user.getUserId());
PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(user);
PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
```

Again, if the user is trying to check if *they* belong to a role, you may get an false negative if they do not have permission to view that role.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Vonderhaar. Actually my question was, is there a way to mock currently logged in user instead of hardcoding the userId . I'm already using the RoleLocalServiceUtil to check the needed.

Comment: @user3487063 Yes, you can mock the user.  Answer updated.  The reason I gave my initial explanation is that you may get a false negative on your test in certain situations, but it is possible to pretend to be another user.